# Nested form not passing attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, nested-forms

I have many models like `Entity`, `person`, `stuff`, `box`. All of them in controller Create action has this code `@entity = Entity.new(entity_params.merge(user: current_user))`.

This code makes perfect association when I make each new Model record. But when I fill nested form from `Entity.controller` only `Entity` gets user_id association. All other `person`, `stuff` ... has NULL on `user_id` field.

Don't know how to make this work!

Answer (score 1):

This code looks unusual to me:

```
@entity = Entity.new(entity_params.merge(user: current_user))
```

The rails de-facto would be:

```
@entity = current_user.entities.new
```

And then active record knows about the association even though the ids are blank initially on the new entity. Not sure this is a complete solution but maybe one of your issues.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. When I fill nested form through Entity controller I have to make association between `Box` and `User` using current_user. Purpose is to know which user is responsible for every record so I can display later correct items to current_user.

Comment: Can you add the code for your form view and controller update+new actions